# field-end modifier is not working in SphinxQL

Tags: database, sphinx, sphinxql

When I filtering exact word by column filed-end modifier is not working.

here is the example:

> SELECT * FROM indexTable WHERE MATCH('@column1 ^abc$');

this returns me: (not only exact "abc")

> abc
>
> abc a
>
> abc d

is there any solution in config or syntax to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure the $ is actully making it into the sql query, it might be being consumed by what ever lanauge your application is written in. eg PHP thinks it means a variable when in a double quoted string.

2) What version of sphinx are you using. Use the latest. A few versions had the field end modifier broken.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i'm using latest version 2.0.6 and run that sql in console (mysql).

Comment: Fixed. The problem was settings in sphinx.conf. I've setup the following params and fixed:  min_word_len = 1 min_infix_len = 1

Comment: Those settings shouldnt have any effect. Would suggest it was just that act of changing those settings, and thereby regenerating your index that fixed it. A side effect not an actual effect.